# Getting the datasource Location of all Renderings inside the page using SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I'm creating a script that would list down all the components in the a particular page then displays the
RenderingItemName, RenderingItemID, RenderingItemPath, RenderingDatasource, etc.,

The script works for getting the information I need except for the datasource,

But for Datasource I am getting Datasource ItemID , How Can I get Datasource Path

```
write-host 'Running script...'
Set-Location master:\sitecore\content\NL\site1 
$pages = get-item master:\sitecore\content\NL\site1\Splash | get-childitem -Recurse
$device = Get-LayoutDevice -Default
$Results = @();
$DataPath = "C:\Components\ComponentsInUse.csv"     

function Test-DataSourceRequired {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Sitecore.Data.ID]$RenderingId)

    $rendering = Get-Item master: -ID $RenderingId
    
    # if data source location and data source template are empty then it's ok for the rendering to have no data source defined
    return -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering."Datasource Location") -or -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering."Datasource Template")
}
 
foreach($page in $pages){
 
    $renderings = Get-Rendering -Item $page -Device $device -FinalLayout -Language "nl-nl" | Where-Object { (Test-DataSourceRequired $_.ItemID) }
 
    foreach($rendering in $renderings){
 
        if($rendering.ItemID -ne $null)
        {
            $renderingItem = Get-Item master: -ID $rendering.ItemID
            if($renderingItem -ne $null)
            {
                $Properties = @{
                    RenderingItemName = $renderingItem.Name
                    RenderingItemID = $renderingItem.ID
                    RenderingItemPath = $renderingItem.Paths.Path
                    RenderingDatasource = $rendering.Datasource
                    UsedOnPage = $page.Name
                    UsedOnPageID = $page.ID
                    UsedOnPagePath = $page.Paths.Path
                }
 
                $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
            }
        }
 
    }
}
 
$Results | Select-Object RenderingItemName,RenderingItemID,RenderingItemPath,RenderingDatasource,UsedOnPage,UsedOnPageID,UsedOnPagePath | Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path $DataPath
 
write-host 'Script ended'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this as below. Get the Item from id and then get its path.

```
$item = Get-Item master: -ID $rendering.Datasource

$item.Paths.FullPath
```

So your script will be like this -

```
write-host 'Running script...'
Set-Location master:\sitecore\content\NL\site1 
$pages = get-item master:\sitecore\content\NL\site1\Splash | get-childitem -Recurse
$device = Get-LayoutDevice -Default
$Results = @();
$DataPath = "C:\Components\ComponentsInUse.csv"     

function Test-DataSourceRequired {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Sitecore.Data.ID]$RenderingId)

    $rendering = Get-Item master: -ID $RenderingId    

    # if data source location and data source template are empty then it's ok for the rendering to have no data source defined
    return -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering."Datasource Location") -or -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering."Datasource Template")
}
 
foreach($page in $pages){
 
    $renderings = Get-Rendering -Item $page -Device $device -FinalLayout -Language "nl-nl" | Where-Object { (Test-DataSourceRequired $_.ItemID) }
 
    foreach($rendering in $renderings){
        $datasouceItem = Get-Item master: -ID $rendering.Datasource        
        if($rendering.ItemID -ne $null)
        {
            $renderingItem = Get-Item master: -ID $rendering.ItemID

            if($renderingItem -ne $null)
            {
                $Properties = @{
                    RenderingItemName = $renderingItem.Name
                    RenderingItemID = $renderingItem.ID
                    RenderingItemPath = $renderingItem.Paths.Path
                    RenderingDatasource = $datasouceItem.Paths.FullPath
                    UsedOnPage = $page.Name
                    UsedOnPageID = $page.ID
                    UsedOnPagePath = $page.Paths.Path
                }
 
                $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
            }
        }
 
    }
}
 
$Results | Select-Object RenderingItemName,RenderingItemID,RenderingItemPath,RenderingDatasource,UsedOnPage,UsedOnPageID,UsedOnPagePath | Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path $DataPath
 
write-host 'Script ended'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the rendering datasource path by adding the below code:

```
 $item =Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $rendering.Datasource
 $renderingDataSourcePath=$item.Paths.Path
```

and add `$renderingDataSourcePath` in the below code:-

```
$Properties = @{
                    RenderingItemName = $renderingItem.Name
                    RenderingItemID = $renderingItem.ID
                    RenderingItemPath = $renderingItem.Paths.Path
                    RenderingDatasource = $renderingDataSourcePath
                    UsedOnPage = $page.Name
                    UsedOnPageID = $page.ID
                    UsedOnPagePath = $page.Paths.Path
                }
```

If you are getting the ItemId in datasource then add this code. If you are getting datasource as a path then add it directly in the variable.

```
if(-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering.Datasource))
 {
     if(Test-IsGuid -ObjectGuid $rendering.Datasource)
       {
         $item =Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $rendering.Datasource
         $renderingDataSourcePath=$item.Paths.Path
       }
}
else
{
$renderingDataSourcePath=$rendering.Datasource
}
```

We add datasource as Id as well as path so we need to check both cases.

Your script will be like this :-

```
write-host 'Running script...'
Set-Location master:\sitecore\content\NL\site1 
$pages = get-item master:\sitecore\content\NL\site1\Splash | get-childitem -Recurse
$device = Get-LayoutDevice -Default
$Results = @();
$DataPath = "C:\Components\ComponentsInUse.csv"     

function Test-DataSourceRequired {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Sitecore.Data.ID]$RenderingId)

    $rendering = Get-Item master: -ID $RenderingId
    
    # if data source location and data source template are empty then it's ok for the rendering to have no data source defined
    return -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering."Datasource Location") -or -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering."Datasource Template")
}
 
foreach($page in $pages){
 
    $renderings = Get-Rendering -Item $page -Device $device -FinalLayout -Language "nl-nl" | Where-Object { (Test-DataSourceRequired $_.ItemID) }
 
    foreach($rendering in $renderings){
 
        if($rendering.ItemID -ne $null)
        {
            $renderingItem = Get-Item master: -ID $rendering.ItemID
            if(-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering.Datasource))
            {
                if(Test-IsGuid -ObjectGuid $rendering.Datasource)
                {
                  $item =Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $rendering.Datasource
                  $renderingDataSourcePath=$item.Paths.Path
                }
            }
            else
            {
                 $renderingDataSourcePath=$rendering.Datasource
            }

            if($renderingItem -ne $null)
            {
                $Properties = @{
                    RenderingItemName = $renderingItem.Name
                    RenderingItemID = $renderingItem.ID
                    RenderingItemPath = $renderingItem.Paths.Path
                    RenderingDatasource = $renderingDataSourcePath
                    UsedOnPage = $page.Name
                    UsedOnPageID = $page.ID
                    UsedOnPagePath = $page.Paths.Path
                }
 
                $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
            }
        }
 
    }
}
 
$Results | Select-Object RenderingItemName,RenderingItemID,RenderingItemPath,RenderingDatasource,UsedOnPage,UsedOnPageID,UsedOnPagePath | Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path $DataPath
 
write-host 'Script ended'
```